# Setting up port based vhosts on 15.04

Tags: apache2

I've bounced back and forth across the web searching for answers but with no luck.  I'm trying to set up port based vhosts and I can get the default :80 port to work, but my other vhosts both return "You don't have permission to access / on this server.".

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/user/website

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**site1.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/user/site1

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**site2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/user/site2

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**ports.conf**

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8081

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

a2ensite has been run on all three sites and service apache2 reload has been run with no posted errors.

There is a simple `index.html` page in each directory so I can tell which site is loading.  `[ipaddress]` or `[ipaddress]:80` shows the `000-default.conf` index page.  `[ipaddress]:8080` and `[ipaddress]:8081` both come back with

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Any help for a noob would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that you have the index files stored in a user's home. What are the permissions on that directory?

Comment: Directories and files are 755, and are owned by the user.

Comment: Okay, I know your issue, I'll post an answer.

Comment: 15.04 is way past End of Life.

Answer (score 1):

In order for Apache to display pages/files hosted in a virtual server, you need to make sure that they are owned by the `www-data` user, as that is the user which Apache runs under. Make sure that you do the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data: /path/to/virtual/server/document/root
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/virtual/server/document/root
```

for each of the virtual servers you have configured.

### But wait! Now *my* user can't modify those files!

Easy fix! You just need to add your user to the `www-data` group!

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data youruser
```

Log out, then log back in for the group changes to take effect, and everything will be good.

### Still not working?

Add the following lines to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /home/user>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then run `sudo service apache2 reload` and all should work.

Comment: I want to point out that all three websites are in the user's home directory, and all three are configured identically.  The website on the default port works fine, the other two give the no permission error.

However, I did make your changes making all three websites owned by www-data and re-running chmod just to make sure and I get the same results.  Only the default port 80 displays the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add:

```
    <Directory /home/user/siteN>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

To each of the `.conf` files.  Files can be owned by the user, they do not need to be owned by `www-data` if the user has been added to the `www-data` group.